# how to add nested collection in firebase v9?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
// written for firebase v8 -->
db.collection("users")
          .doc(user?.id)
          .collection("orders")
          .doc(paymentIntent.id)
          .set({
            basket: basket,
            amount: paymentIntent.amount,
            created: paymentIntent.created,
          });
```

----> // How to write this same code for firebase v9?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The equivalent in v9 would be:

```
const paymentRef = doc(db, "users", user?.id, "orders", paymentIntent.id);
setDoc(paymentRef, {
  basket: basket,
  amount: paymentIntent.amount,
  created: paymentIntent.created,
});
```

Comment: thank you so much @Frank...it worked! yay...you have no idea how much you helped me...thanks alot :)